# Rails show string not ID in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, grouped-collection-select

I have the following form where a user selects a department from a list of database entries on the activity centers page.  I am trying to display the department string (`:department`) instead of the department ID.  I tried `@activity_center.department.department` but that isn't working.  Any suggestions?

Form:

```
<%= f.select :department_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@departments, 'id', 'department'), hide_label: true, :multiple => false %>
```

Departments Model:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :department, :presence => true
    has_many :activity_centers
end
```

Activity Centers Model:

```
class ActivityCenter < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :activity_center, :presence => true
    validates :department_id, :presence => true
    belongs_to :departments
end
```

Activity centers index page:

```
<% @activity_centers.each do |activity_center| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= activity_center.activity_center %></td>
      <td><%= activity_center.department.department %></td>
      <td style="text-align:right;">
        <%= link_to 'View Activity Center',  activity_center_path(activity_center),      class: "btn btn-success btn-xs" %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit',           edit_activity_center_path(activity_center), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete',         activity_center_path(activity_center),      class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs",
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Confirm you want to delete this activity_center.' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: my first question is in the "Activity Centers Model:"  is it  `belongs_to :departments` or `belongs_to :department`  I think you have it singular

Comment: YES! Thank you so much for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Per  MZaragoza it was a typo.  `belongs_to` is supposed to be singular.